# How to co-ordinate item from ng-repeat with $index

Tags: angularjs, indexing, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have used ng-repeat on `<tr>` to create rows in a table based on ng-repeat's filter and sort like `ng-repeat="patent in patents | searchFilter"`.

Now I am trying to implement select rows with "shift" click and "Ctrl" click by implementing some thing like `item.select = true`.

The index of items in `<tr>` are not in co-ordination with $index.

Does anyone know how to pick an item of `<tr>` with the help of $index like `$("#patientsTb tr")[$index].pickItem()`.

**View:**

```
<table id="patientsTb" class="table table-condensed table_back" style="min-width:370px; overflow:scroll;">
                    <tr ng-repeat="patient in patients | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | filter:{isPatientSeen: patientDetailView} | filter:searchPatient"
                        ng-click="editPatient(patient,$index,$event)"
                        ng-class="{'selected':patient.selected}">
                        @*<td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="patient.selected" ng-click="chkUnchkRow(patient,$event)" ng-disabled="isDataLoading || isEditPatient" />&nbsp;&nbsp;{{$index+1}}</td>*@
                        <td style="padding-left:5px;">{{patient.accountNumber}}</td>
                        <td style="padding-left:15px;">{{patient.medicalRecordNumber}}</td>
                        <td ng-show="siteType=='HL'" style="padding-left:10px;">{{patient.encounterCount}}</td>
                        <td style="padding-left:20px;">{{patient.patientLastName}}</td>
                        <td style="padding-left:20px;">{{patient.patientFirstName}}</td>
                        <td style="padding-left:20px;">{{patient.note}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

**Controller:**

```
    $scope.editPatient = function (patient, index, e) {                  
                if (e.shiftKey) {                        
                    angular.forEach($scope.patients, function (value, i) {
                        //if (value.selected && $scope.firstIndex == -1) {
                        //    firstIndex = i;
                        //}
                        value.selected = false;
                    });

                    for (var indexOfRows = $scope.firstIndex; indexOfRows <= index; indexOfRows++) {
                        $('#patientsTb tr').eq(indexOfRows).toggleClass('selected');
                    }

                    angular.forEach($scope.patients, function (value, i) {
                        if (i >= $scope.firstIndex && i <= index) {
                            value.selected = !value.selected;
                        }
                    });

                }
                else if (e.ctrlkey) {
                    patient.selected = !patient.selected;
                }
                else {
                    angular.forEach($scope.patients, function (value, i) {
                        value.selected = false;
                    });
                    $scope.firstIndex = index;
                    patient.selected = true;
                }
};
```

Comment: Please provide relevant html and controller code. There is no need to use jQuery for this.

Comment: @charlietfl please check the details of my questions for the view and controller code. Thanks

Comment: you are already using `ng-class` for when patient is selected. no need for the jQuery as duplication using toggleClass

Comment: ng-class helps to set selected for one selected row. But I need to implement shift select multiple rows.

Comment: well there are numerous modules you can use to do that. I just did a quick web search and found lots of resources

Answer (score 0):

You can create a service that maintains an array of selected rows, and exposes some helper methods that let you toggle rows and check if they are selected. You can then use this service in your controller and view.

**RowService**

```
angular.module('rowSelect').service('RowService', RowService);

function RowService () {
  var self = this,
      selectedRows = [];

  self.toggleRow = toggleRow;
  self.isSelected = isSelected;

  function toggleRow (index) {
    if (self.isSelected(index)) {
      selectedRows.splice(selectedRows.indexOf(index), 1);
    } else {
      selectedRows.push(index);
    }
  } 

  function isSelected (index) {
    return !!~selectedRows.indexOf(index);
  }
}
```

**Controller**

```
angular.module('rowSelect').controller('MainController', MainController);

function MainController ($scope, RowService) {
  $scope.toggleRow = RowService.toggleRow;
  $scope.isSelected = RowService.isSelected;
}
```

**View**

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in items | searchFilter" 
    ng-class="{'active':isSelected($index)}" 
    ng-click="toggleRow($index)">
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

It occurs to me that what you could try, without any JQuery code or index usage is to do the following:

**HTML**

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in items | searchFilter" 
    ng-class="{'active':item.selected}" 
    ng-click="item.selected = !item.selected">
</tr>
```

This way, each time an element is clicked into, it's `selected` preoperty will be set. Now you can use `selected` prop to retrieve the list of items that are selected (or not)